# how to make one function stop working while key get pressed and get line bolder?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make the white line stop moving when i press 'w'. How can I do than? And how can I make it bolder? The white line need to move in circeler mution and when the user press 'w' the line need to stop moving.

```
PIVOT = (WINDOW_WIDTH/2, 150)
SWINGLENGTH = PIVOT[1]*0.8


def fill():

class Pendulum(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


pen = Pendulum()

TICK = USEREVENT + 2
pygame.time.set_timer(TICK, TIMETICK)

def input(events):
    for event in events:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == TICK:
            pen.update()

#while True:
 #   input(pygame.event.get())
  #  pygame.display.flip()


finish = False
while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True

        while True:
            input(pygame.event.get())
            pygame.display.flip()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_w:
            #if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_w:
            print('Forward')
            fill()
            #screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
            #input(pygame.event.get())
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to get the current sate of all keys.

Check by `pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]`, if the <kbd>w</kbd> is pressed:

e.g.

```py
finish = False
while not finish:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True

    allKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # move the white line if 'w' is not pressed 
    if not allKeys[pygame.K_w]:            

        # [...]

    pygame.display.flip()
```